# Git tag hook for checking git externals file for untagged references

Tags: git, tags, hook

Is there any possibility to check git_externals file for untagged references while you make git tag?

Comment: I was just experimenting with client hooks and didn't find one that fired when a lightweight or annotated tag was created, otherwise you might have been able to do work there.

Comment: Maybe create an alias that you use to do extra work when you make a git tag?

Comment: @DavidN the preferable way for me to use server side hook, however, I understand that I can analyze git tag object only. So, it seems local hooks is the only solution right now.

Comment: @DavidN I want to inject this solution for several developers, so I need a general solution, that is why alias might not be the best solution for that. However, it is good idea!